# Heroku: procfile in subdirectory

Tags: heroku

I have a git repository for a project with many parts of the stack in their own subdirectories. Something like this:

```
.
..
./A
./B
./C
 ./Procfile
 ./packjage.json
./D
```

Folder C is the only part of this application that I want to run on Heroku, but Heroku doesn't like procfiles that aren't at the root of the repository.

Is there anyway to tell Heroku where your procfile/package.json are? Or will I somehow have to split up a very large repository (which I don't really want to do)?

Answer (score 6):

Have a look at [this](https://elements.heroku.com/buildpacks/sjtrny/subdir-depend-heroku-buildpack).

Your Procfile must be in the root directory as mentioned in another answer here.

If you have a project tree like this:

```
- Procfile
- requirements.txt
- data/
    - data.csv
- src/
    - app.py
```

You can tell gunicorn to change to this subdirectory first and point to src/app.py

Your Procfile should look like this:

```
web: gunicorn --chdir ./src app:app
```

Answer (score 2):

The Procfile [must be](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile#process-types-as-templates) in the root directory. You can't put it anywhere else - that's the only place that is searched.

Comment: so how do I reference `server.js` (which is located in subfolder) in `Procfile`?